# Best way to store a button toggle state in a Cookie (or possibly Session Storage)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies, session-cookies, session-storage

I am trying to build a button which toggles a dark-mode on and off.

When the user clicks the button, it should add the class `.dark` to the body tag and store the state in a cookie.

This cookie should be stored for the entire session. On page load, a function should check if this cookie exist and add the class `.dark` to the body tag.

Likewise, if the cookie already exists (or if the body tag already has the class `.dark`), the button should do exactly the opposite - clicking it should remove the class `.dark` from the body and and delete the cookie (or change its value - whatever makes more sense to you).

I have tried using the jQuery plugin [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie) for this and this is the code I have come up with so far:

(Somehow this code does nothing here and works better on JSFiddle: [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9kaovfdx/))

```js
// On initial page load, there is not yet a cookie
// When the user clicks the button for the fist time, do this:
$('#night-mode').click(function() {

 // create a cookie for darkmode state
 Cookies.set('_darkmode', 'Enabled');
  
 // add class to body
 $('body').addClass('dark');
});

// If darkmode is already active, do this instead:
$('body.dark #night-mode').click(function() {

 // remove set darkmode cookie, add lightmode cookie
 Cookies.remove('_darkmode');
 Cookies.set('_lightmode', 'Enabled');
  
 // remove darkmode class and add lightmode class to body
 $('body').removeclass('dark').addClass('light');
  
});

// If lightmode is already active, do this instead:
$('body.light #night-mode').click(function() {

 // remove set darkmode cookie, add lightmode cookie
 Cookies.remove('_lightmode');
 Cookies.set('_darkmode', 'Enabled');
  
 // remove lightmode class and add darkmode class to body
 $('body').removeclass('light').addClass('dark');
  
});
```

```css
#night-mode {
 margin: 2em auto;
 display: block;
}

body {
  color: green;
}

body.dark {
  color: red;
}

body.light {
  color: blue;
}

p {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.3/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<button id="night-mode" class="night">Toggle</button>

<p>Green = no cookie</p>
<p>Red = dark mode is active</p>
<p>Blue = light mode is active</p>
```

For some obvious reasons which my amateur brain can't comprehend, this does not work.

So I would like to ask: What is the best way to achieve this? Possibly without any jQuery plugin and maybe even with Session Storage instead of cookies? I have no more ideas about how to get this right.

Thanks!

Comment: You're not defining the body anywhere, either in the code provided here nor in the JSFiddle. You'd have to add the class "dark" to the body depending on the cookie content. Check this fork of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/zr02tgn3/ where I added another div getting the "dark" class depending on the cookie.

Comment: Hmm, this doesn't seem to do more than my jsFiddle code (set dark mode cookie) and instead gives me some errors in the console log.. But Im sure this is going in the right direction

Comment: Would you mind trying this one and let me know which, if any, error(s) you receive? http://jsfiddle.net/zr02tgn3/4/

Comment: The "console.log(dark_cookie);" instead returns "undefined" in the console.. 

But thats not so important. What your code does is add a a class to the "night-mode-test" div if the cookie is enabled. But after that, I still can not use the button to do the oppposite..

Comment: That should not be a problem, the button adds the `dark` class to that div when the cookie is undefined. It works perfectly for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close... The only thing left to add was to read the cookie on load.

And you had a typo on `addClass()` where it needs a capital.

Another important thing, when you define `$('body.light #night-mode')` and the body does not have the class light on load... The handler is NOT set. So just define `$('#night-mode').click(function() {` and use some conditions to check if the body has a class...

```
if(Cookies.get("_darkmode")=="Enabled"){
  $("body").addClass('dark');
  console.log("Cookie dark is set on load");
}
if(Cookies.get("_lightmode")=="Enabled"){
  $("body").addClass('light');
  console.log("Cookie dark is set on load");
}

// On initial page load, there is not yet a cookie
// When the user clicks the button for the fist time, do this:
$('#night-mode').click(function() {
  if($("body").hasClass("dark")){
    // remove set darkmode cookie, add lightmode cookie
    Cookies.remove('_darkmode');
    Cookies.set('_lightmode', 'Enabled');
    // remove darkmode class and add lightmode class to body
    $('body').removeClass('dark').addClass('light');
    console.log("Setted Cookie dark");
  }
  else if($("body").hasClass("light")){
    // remove set darkmode cookie, add lightmode cookie
    Cookies.remove('_lightmode');
    Cookies.set('_darkmode', 'Enabled');
    // remove lightmode class and add darkmode class to body
    $('body').removeClass('light').addClass('dark');
    console.log("Setted Cookie light");
  }else{
    // create a cookie for darkmode state
    Cookies.set('_darkmode', 'Enabled');
    // add class to body
    $('body').addClass('dark');
    console.log("Setted Cookie dark for the first time");
  }
});
```

Your [updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bes7weB/80mxoh3w/2/)

Comment: Not only does this work perfectly but you also helped me understand what exactly I did wrong. Thanks!

Comment: That's what SO is made for! Have a nice day!